# What's the best adjective to define a person's attitude to project thoughts into the future?

Tags: adjectives, idiom-requests

Regardless if optimistic, negative, or realistic, it should depict an innate quality or ability, rather than a professional skill. I'm not trying to adjectivalize the scientific thinking of a sociologist analyzing and studying possible futures.
I'll take an excerpt from [Gallup Strengthsfinder blog](http://www.gallup.com/businessjournal/673/futuristic.aspx) to focus the question, which better describes the persona that I have in mind:

> [...] You are the kind of person who loves to peer over the horizon. The future fascinates you. As if it were projected on the wall, you see in detail what the future might hold, and this detailed picture keeps pulling you forward, into tomorrow. While the exact content of the picture will depend on your other strengths and interests -- a better product, a better team, a better life, or a better world -- it will always be inspirational to you. [...]

Even if "futuristic" (rather than "dreamer") would be acceptable, I think it's better to use it to describe the look-and-feel and the qualities of a product, especially technological ones.

Is there a word which best suits?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps **visionary**?

From [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/visionary):

> - someone who has visions; a seer
> - an impractical dreamer
> - someone who has positive ideas about the future

Answer (score 2):

Forward-thinking, forward-looking, progressive.